# Gradle deploying a Jar file

Tags: deployment, jar, gradle

I would like to create a build.gradle file to pack some classes into a jar and deploy this jar somewhere. As an example, I created a class hello.class (classic HelloWorld) and a build.gradle:

```
task hello(type : Jar) {
    archiveName = "hello.jar"
    destinationDir = file("/home/GradleTest")
    destFile = file("/home/GradleTest/hello.jar")
    from("/home/GradleTest") }
```

When I try launch gradle (`gradle build`), I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/GradleTest/build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GradleTest'.
> No such property: destFile for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar_Decorated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.153 secs
```

Does anyone know what is the problem? I give you the result of my `gradle -v` command:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-07-01 07:45:34 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b6ead6fa452dfdadec484059191eb641d817226c

Groovy:       2.3.3
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-24-generic amd64
```

Thank you much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such property as `destFile`. You can use `archiveFile`. It will give you this value without the need to assign it. At least that's what I see when I look at the documentation - http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

Comment: Seems that removing the line is sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this done with (thanks to @radim's answer)

```
task createJar(type : Jar) {
    def originDir = file("${buildDir}/unpacked")
    def destinationFile = "${buildDir}/repackaged/${project.name}-${version}"
    archiveName = destinationFile
    from(originDir)
    archiveFile
}
```